# Android Error: NullPointerException being thrown

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onclick, onclicklistener

My code consists of an XML gridview in which 64 imageviews are laid out in a chessboard pattern. My java is supposed to monitor for clicks on those imageViews with actual images inside of them and then execute the supplied code.

However, at runtime my emulator is presenting me with a dialogue box saying "Unfortunately, chessboard stopped working" and logcat is throwing a NullPointerException like so: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

I'm not not sure where the null is being generated. I know that I'm checking for null but I don't see how that could be generating the error.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class chessboard extends ActionBarActivity {


    public Activity board;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.board);

        final ImageView block2 = (ImageView) board.findViewById(R.id.block2);
        block2.setClickable(true);
        block2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (block2.getTag() != (null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Check", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: `board` is null because that's the default value for reference fields if you don't set them to anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `findViewById` on your `board` variable, `board` is `null`.

If you change this line

```
final ImageView block2 = (ImageView) board.findViewById(R.id.block2);
```

to this

```
final ImageView block2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.block2);
```

You will not get the `NullPointerException`.

Additionally, this code is not needed

```
public Activity board;
```

Since you inflate your layout by calling `setContentView` and can get your references directly from your `Activity`